# How can I get my return value from stored procedure to display on GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a return value from the stored procedure `GetTeam`, and I want it to be displayed in the Gridview. This is what I have, but it is not displaying in the gridview:

```
protected void getTeam()
{
    SqlConnection con;
    string CS = Configuration.Manager.ConnectionStrings["TEAM"].ConnectionString;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using(con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetTeam",con);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlAdapter(cmd);
        da.fill(dt);

        Gridview1.Datasource = dt;
        Gridview1.Databind();
    }
}
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Share your stored procedure code too please

Comment: It's really long, but I have a return (at)return_value and I want the @return_value to be displayed on the gridview.

Comment: If you step through this code with a debugger, can you see whether your data is populating on the data table in memory? It would help us narrow down on whether the stored procedure is the problem or whether it's how you're using the gridview.

Comment: What is there in `@return_value` ? One value , multiple values?

Comment: Use out parameter if it's a scalar value. create a blank row in Datatable and append the value as you like to. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/05/07/a-simple-example-on-how-to-get-return-and-out-parameter-values-using-ado-net/

Comment: search google and find thousands of examples

Comment: On an unrelated note, your `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` can (and should) both be wrapped in a `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this solution below, keep in this solution we are sending a parameter to help narrow our results to specific team.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
 {
            //Connection string
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString.DataSourceString;

            //Create adapter and assign store procedure name
            SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand()
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            // Assign to Command type
            //exception is caught because it cannot find Stored Procedure

            //Insert parameters into row from input text
            cmmd.CommandText = "GetTeam";
    // Send parameter            
cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PGetDayTeam",
 ShiftParameterTextBox.Text.Trim());

            cmmd.Connection = conn;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                //If we do not receive any records 
                GridView2.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
                GridView2.DataSource = cmmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView2.DataBind();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close and dispose connection
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
 // select from grid
protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{

GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];


        string GetTeam = row.Cells[2].Text;
       // You can use it in viewstate or what you choose.
        ViewState["GetTeam"] = GetTeam;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Fill operation then adds the rows to destination DataTable objects
>   in the DataSet, creating the DataTable objects if they do not already
>   exist. When creating DataTable objects, the Fill operation normally
>   creates only column name metadata. However, if the MissingSchemaAction
>   property is set to AddWithKey, appropriate primary keys and
>   constraints are also created.

You're using sql prosedure. So you already have a Colums' name. You don't need to use DataTable. The Sql adapter can fill dataset also. You need to use DataSet first.

```
public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
        {
            //create a command and prepare it for execution
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, transaction, commandType, commandText, commandParameters);

            //create the DataAdapter & DataSet
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            //fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc.
            da.Fill(ds);

            //return the dataset
            return ds;
        }
```

Then you can bind your Gridview with that one.

```
grdView.DataSource = ds;
grdView.DataBind();
```